# UpdateException: 0 related 'TestTakers' were found. 1 'TestTakers' is expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out with Entity Framework 3.5 (it works when using EF 4 (with slight changes in the code to accommodate EF 4), but because of the server I am using, need to use EF 3.5). My ASP.NET app allows users to take a simple true/false test. After the user completes the test, hits the Submit button where it calculates a score, a percent rank, and then writes data back to the database (SQL Server 2008R2). It writes to the TestTaker model just fine, but generates the following exception when attempting to write to the TestTakerAnswer model:

**System.Data.UpdateException: Entities in 'ComplianceTestContext.TestTakerAnswers' participate in the 'FK_TestTakerAnswers_TestTakers' relationship. 0 related 'TestTakers' were found. 1 'TestTakers' is expected.**

I have seen questions like this posted before, but still was not able to figure out my problem. Shown below is a subset of the EDM and the event handler for when the Submit button is selected. Any help with this would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

```
  protected void wizTest_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
  {
     // Score test and display result.
     ///////////////////////////////////
     int score = 0;
     double rank;

     using (var db = new ComplianceTestContext())
     {
        // Get reference to wizard control.
        ContentPlaceHolder cph1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        Wizard wizControl = (Wizard)cph1.FindControl("wizTest");

        // 1. Calculate score.
        var questions = from q in db.TestQuestions
                        orderby q.QuestionNumber
                        select q;

        foreach (var item in questions)
        {
           var rdoBtnList = (RadioButtonList)wizControl.FindControl("rdoQ" + item.QuestionNumber);

           if (item.Answer == (rdoBtnList.SelectedValue == "1"))
           {
              score += item.Weight;
           }
        }

        // ==========================================================================================================================================================

        // 2. Calculate percent rank.
        var testTakers = from tt in db.TestTakers
                         orderby tt.Score
                         select tt;

        int totalScores = testTakers.Count() + 101;  // 101 = 1 + (current score) + 100 (salted number of scores).
        int totalScoresWithGrade;

        if (score >= 277)
        {
           // Get total number of A grades for calculating top x% rank.
           totalScoresWithGrade = testTakers.Count(tt => tt.Score >= 277) + 3;  // 3 = 1 + (current A score) + 2 (salted number of A scores).
        }
        else if (score >= 246 && score <= 276)
        {
           // Get total number of B grades for calculating top x% rank.
           totalScoresWithGrade = testTakers.Count(tt => tt.Score >= 246) + 26;  // 26 = 1 + (current B score) + 23 (salted number of B scores) + 2 (salted number of A scores).
        }
        else if (score >= 215 && score <= 245)
        {
           // Get total number of C grades.
           totalScoresWithGrade = testTakers.Count(tt => tt.Score >= 215 && tt.Score <= 245) + 55;  // 55 = 1 + (current C score) + 54 (salted number of C scores).
        }
        else if (score >= 186 && score <= 214)
        {
           // Get total number of D grades for calculating bottom x% rank.
           totalScoresWithGrade = testTakers.Count(tt => tt.Score <= 214) + 22;  // 22 = 1 + (current D score) + 19 (salted number of D scores) + 2 (salted number of F scores).
        }
        else
        {
           // Get total number of F grades for calculating bottom x% rank.
           totalScoresWithGrade = testTakers.Count(tt => tt.Score <= 185) + 3;  // 3 = 1 + (current F score) + 2 (salted number of F scores).
        }

        rank = Convert.ToDouble(totalScoresWithGrade) / totalScores;

        // ==========================================================================================================================================================

        // 3. Write data to TestTaker model.
        var testTaker = new TestTaker { DateTaken = DateTime.Now, Score = score };
        db.AddToTestTakers(testTaker);
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Retrieve newly inserted row's TestTakerId (identity column) for use in inserting data into TestTakerAnswer model.
        int testTakerId = testTaker.TestTakerId;

        // ==========================================================================================================================================================

        // 4. Write data to TestTakerAnswer model.
        foreach (var item in questions)
        {
           var rdoBtnList = (RadioButtonList)wizControl.FindControl("rdoQ" + item.QuestionNumber);
           var answer = new TestTakerAnswer { AnswerNumber = item.QuestionNumber, TestTakerId = testTakerId, Answer = (rdoBtnList.SelectedValue == "1") };
           db.AddToTestTakerAnswers(answer);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
     }

     // 5. Display score to user.
     var testScoreMsg = "Your test score is " + score;
     var testRankingMsg = string.Empty;

     if (score >= 277)
     {
        testRankingMsg = string.Format("Congratulations. Your company receives an A. This means you are ranked in the top {0:P1} of our participants and clients.", rank);
     }
     else if (score >= 246 && score <= 276)
     {
        testRankingMsg = string.Format("Your company receives a B. This means you are ranked in the top {0:P1} of our participants and clients.", rank);
     }
     else if (score >= 215 && score <= 245)
     {
        testRankingMsg = string.Format("Your company receives a C. This means you are ranked in the middle {0:P1} of our participants and clients.", rank);
     }
     else if (score >= 186 && score <= 214)
     {
        testRankingMsg = string.Format("Your company receives a D. This means you are ranked in the bottom {0:P1} of our participants and clients.", rank);
     }
     else
     {
        testRankingMsg = string.Format("Your company receives an F. This means you are ranked in the bottom {0:P1} of our participants and clients.", rank);
     }

     lblScore.Text = testScoreMsg;
     lblRank.Text = testRankingMsg;
  }
```

Comment: I think this is because you don't have a matching TestTakerId in the TestTaker table.  Check the TestTakerId during debug and verify it exists in the database.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed the existence of the TestTakerId, so that is not the issue. Thanks for the feedback.